# 3D Card Slider using Angular6

Tags: typescript, angular6, nodes

Is there any library for 3d Card Slider like below image using Angular6[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see it is question just about styles for any slides library. I didn't find any package with ready same styles, but you can add it by yourself. You just need make neighbour slides visible and slight descrese them size. [Here is](https://medium.com/@asm/animated-slide-panel-with-angular-e985ad646f9) an article with example of slides realisation